# Convert images and animated gifs to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif

I use the following FFMpeg command to convert images to video.

```
for file in %N; do ffmpeg -framerate 15 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -vf "scale=min(1920/iw\,1920/ih)*iw:min(1920/iw\,1920/ih)*ih,pad=1920:1920:(1920-(min(1920/iw\,1920/ih)*iw))/2:(1920-(min(1920/iw\,1920/ih)*ih))/2" -c:v libx264 output.mp4; done
```

Assuming I have a folder with JPGs and animated GIF files what command can I use so that both the JPGs and GIFs are converted into the same video output?

The way I'm doing it now is to extract the GIFs to JPGs and then convert to video, but I'd rather combine the images and animated GIFs with one command.

NOTE: I'm not asking how to convert GIFs to video. But how to convert still images *and* animated GIFs to video with one command.

Comment: before your loop set : `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")` It causes if your file name contains space or other scape code, ffmpeg ignore them.

Comment: Place it before "for file in %N;"? How will this help me with combining images and animated gifs into video?

Comment: Oh, if you want to cp or mv it's needed, because may be your files contain space or other chars.

Comment: I'm not really worried about modifying it to work with filenames with spaces. I just want a command that will convert still images and animated gifs to video with one command.

Comment: The best solution I found was to unpack the gif with the following command: convert -coalesce %F %n.jpg